# Tensorflow dataset TFDS Build takes all the ram

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with over 2M images and a 16GB RAM. When I do tfds build, it fills all the RAM at around 1M image mark. (Even though it is yeilding it):
This is my code in `builder.py` file.

```
    def _generate_examples(self, path, df=df):
        """Yields examples."""
        for class_label in os.listdir(path):
            class_path = os.path.join(path, class_label)
            if os.path.isdir(class_path):
                for file_path in os.listdir(class_path):
                    full_file_path = os.path.join(class_path, file_path)

                    # Process and yield the image data
                    try:
                        processed_image = cv2.cvtColor(
                            cv2.imread(full_file_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB
                        )
                        processed_image = preprocess_image(processed_image)
                        processed_image = np.array(processed_image, dtype=np.uint8)
                        yield file_path, {
                            "image": processed_image,
                            "label": class_label,
                        }
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error processing image {full_file_path}: {e}")
```

How can I reduce the memory usage of it and make sure it runs compeltly. (It do around 30 Images persecond for now), so painfully slow as well.